# itertools not iterating for tsv files line number

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a tsv with 100000 lines of data. When i put `n_rating=55555` it enters the for loop of the code bellow. But when I use the line length of  the file it does not enter into the loop, not for once.

```
with open("u.data") as tsv1:
    n=sum([1 for _ in tsv1 ])
    print n
    for line in itertools.islice( csv.reader(tsv1, dialect="excel-tab"),0, int(0.8*n)):
        print "iterating loop" #does not print when n is line size
                               #prints when n
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as you have it is trying to read the file twice. After the number of lines has been calculated, the file pointer is at the end of the file. By adding [`seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tell#file.seek), you can move to the start of the file again.

```
with open("u.data") as tsv1:
    n = sum([1 for _ in tsv1])
    print n
    tsv1.seek(0)

    for line in itertools.islice( csv.reader(tsv1, dialect="excel-tab"),0, int(0.8*n)):
        print "iterating loop" #does not print when n is line size
                               #prints when n
```